# Apache Archiva Maven releated

Tags: java, apache, maven, devops, archiva

I am trying to use Apache Archiva as my project repository. I configure archiva and am able to upload the snapshot to archiva using mvn deploy since i configured the details in pom.xml and settings.xml respectively.

Now i have snapshots which are under development, and at the time of release, i would like to move the latest artifacts from snapshots to internal(release). May I know the configuration details? I tried with maven release:prepare but it is failing since i have to mention SCM also in that. In this case, it is just about moving artifact from snapshot to internal, a different compilation is not required.

Please help on this.

Comment: The release plugin of maven is rather strict about he process (setting tags, recompiling). 
What you could do, is to rename the file (without compilation) in the target folder and then just upload it (using maven install plugin). 
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html

Please note, that I would not do it in this way, since you do not have this release marked in your SCM and neither you checked the file, that it is still compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using release:perform by mentioned scm pointing to git repository. release:prepare took the checkout and pushed a release as well as created a tag in git.
Thanks